# Bidi post request forbidden but get request works

Tags: clojure, xmlhttprequest, clojurescript, bidi

I am making a get and post requests like so:

```
(http-cljs.client/get "someurl.com/my")
```

and

```
(http-cljs.client/post "someurl.com/my")
```

On the server, I have the route:

```
{"/my" do-something}
```

While do-something runs with the get request, it doesn't with the post and in the client I get 403 forbidden. In the response I get "Invalid Anti-forgery token".

These are the middleware I'm using:

```
(defn config []
  {:http-port  (Integer. (or (env :port) 5000))
   :middleware [[wrap-defaults site-defaults]
                wrap-with-logger
                wrap-gzip

                [wrap-reload {:dir "../../src"}]

                wrap-params
                wrap-keyword-params
                wrap-json-body
                wrap-edn-params

                ]})
```

When I use api-defaults however, there's no 403 forbidden, and it only happens with the site-defaults. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for `wrap-defaults` which is `site-defaults` will turn on the `anti-forgery-middleware`

If you look at the doc string of `wrap-anti-forgery` you will find:

```
"Middleware that prevents CSRF attacks. Any POST request to the handler
  returned by this function must contain a valid anti-forgery token, or else an
  access-denied response is returned.

  The anti-forgery token can be placed into a HTML page via the
  *anti-forgery-token* var, which is bound to a (possibly deferred) token.
  The token is also available in the request under
  `:anti-forgery-token`.

  By default, the token is expected to be POSTed in a form field named
  '__anti-forgery-token', or in the 'X-CSRF-Token' or 'X-XSRF-Token'
  headers.

  Accepts the following options:

  :read-token     - a function that takes a request and returns an anti-forgery
                    token, or nil if the token does not exist

  :error-response - the response to return if the anti-forgery token is
                    incorrect or missing

  :error-handler  - a handler function to call if the anti-forgery token is
                    incorrect or missing

  :strategy       - a strategy for creating and validating anti-forgety tokens,
                    which must satisfy the
                    ring.middleware.anti-forgery.strategy/Strategy protocol
                    (defaults to the session strategy:
                    ring.middleware.anti-forgery.session/session-strategy)

  Only one of :error-response, :error-handler may be specified.
```

Anti-forgery for forms is used to prevent replay attacks.
More info on CSRF attacks here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: forgot to add, you can also turn off anti-forgery by using `(assoc-in site-defaults [:security :anti-forgery] false)`